# Rewrite nginx с картинки на страницу

Tags: nginx, mod_rewrite

Как прописать правило в nginx так что бы при запросе картинки

> http://site.ru/ping/images/324565789/i.png

перенаправлялось на адрес

> http://site.ru/ping/images/324565789/

?

Текст конфига хоста:

```
server {    listen 000.000.000.000:80;    server_name site.ru;    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;    location / {        root /srv/nginx/site/www/;        index index.htm index.html index.php;        autoindex off;        # don’t check $uri/, send to php for nice error message        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;    }    location ~ /\. {        deny all;    }    location ~ \.php$ {        root           /srv/nginx/site/www/;        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;        fastcgi_index  index.php;        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /srv/nginx/site/www/$fastcgi_script_name;        include        fastcgi_params;    }    location ~* \.css|\.js|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif|\.swf|\.svg|\.tiff|\.pdf$ {        root /srv/nginx/site/www/;    }}
```

Дописываю в конце:

```
    location /ping/images/ {        rewrite ^/ping/images/(\d+)/i\.png$ /ping/images/$1/ last;    }
```

выдает 404 (даже на /ping/images/).

Дописываю в конце:

```
location /ping/ {    rewrite ^/ping/images/(.+)/.+\.png$ http://site.ru/ping/images/$1/ break;}
```

выдает 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так должно работать:

```
rewrite ^/ping/images/(\d+)/i\.png$ /ping/images/$1/ redirect;
```

Это простейший вариант, чтобы было легче понять. Я бы еще ужесточил условия регулярных выражений. Например, если после /images/ идут только цифры, то использовал бы `\d+` условие, для названий файлов что-нибудь вроде `[a-z0-9_-]`. В общем, по обстоятельствам.

Подробнее можно посмотреть в [документации nginx](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html).

**UPD:** убрал location, здесь оно лишнее. Спасибо, [[@pyatak](/users/814/pyatak)](/users/814/pyatak), навел на мысль. Задача не сложная, нужно просто внимательнее почитать документацию.

Comment: Сервер отдает 404.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Контекст location был лишним.

Answer (score 1):

Ну дык просто же.... Совсем обленились доки читать

```
rewrite .*(/[0-9]*)/(.*).png $1/ redirect;
```